# How to setup WCF proxy relay service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am writing an ASP.net Dashboard application in C#. The application will collect alarm statistics and display them on the dashboard via Ajax(jQuery).

The application could collect the alarm stats cross domain so we chose to set it up as follows:

A standalone Windows Service runs with a constant connection to the Broker(a program that collects stats). Inside the Windows Service we've hosted a WCF service. The windows service will load pass the string of stats into the WCFExternalService.

We then setup an WCF Service hosted in IIS and referenced inside the Client app( this service will act as a relay/proxy service).

Can someone please point me to an article or explain how to setup the bindings/endpoints to connect the proxy service to the external WCF service?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have already got most of the structure going. My inputs below:

- The WCF proxy (in UI layer) could implement the same service contract as its WCF service counterpart (in Windows service). However, the WCF proxy would be a 'client' of the real WCF service (you need to configure this in Web.config).
- Now, enable the WCF proxy to be consumed by jQuery / JavaScript using `WebInvoke` attribute. `[WebInvoke("GET", WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)]`
- Use jQuery $.ajax syntax to consume your WCF proxy. The `url` should be an equivalent of 'http://myHost/myVirtual/MyProxy.svc/MyMethod' and the `data` should be a JSON string equivalent of your WCF proxy parameters.

**Further explanation on the first point:**

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) MSDN article explains how to set up a WCF client (to be consumed by your proxy WCF).

Next, you can create a proxy WCF service to consume the WCF client.

The Web.config of your website (which contains the proxy) needs sections for WCF client and WCF proxy.

Hosting does not matter in WCF, so your 'real' service could support any binding (Http, Tcp) based on your requirements and environment

Comment: Thanks for your response Channs, in relation to your first bulletpoint do you have a sample of how to do this? I am not sure of exact syntax for the binding endpoints to set this up. Also, in this case will the "Real" WCF Service need to use a tcp binding?

Comment: Also which web.config do I add the settings in?